# Error: Cannot find module 'bootstrap-sprockets'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

Although running bootstrap with rails is working fine, the JS functionality isn't working for me. For example, I can't collapse navbar, but I can run `$()` in my browser console.

My /app/javascript/packs/application.js looks like this:

```js
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require('bootstrap-sprockets')
require('popper.js')
require('turbolinks')

// As instructed in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails 
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
// But the above is not working
```

My /app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss looks like this:

```css
@import "bootstrap" ;

body {
    margin: 0 ;
}
```

In my routes.rb, I have `root to: 'pages#home'`. The home.html.erb looks like this:

```html
<div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
  <main role="main" class="inner cover">
    <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
    <p class="lead">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
    </p>
  </main>

  <footer class="mastfoot mt-auto">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

---

When I run the server, and visit the home page, an error is showing up on the browser's console:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bootstrap-sprockets'
```

My gem file has these entries for jquery, bootstap:

```rb
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.5'
gem "bootstrap", "~> 4.4"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

I can't use features like navbar collapse in bootstrap. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problems with collapse not working, and latest version of jQuery and bootstrap.
Had to change to:
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"jquery": "3.4.1"

But this was with rails 6.0.1, so using ujs. Check those versions.

Comment: Any javascript error on the browser when you try to collapse?

Comment: Nope, but I have fixed the issue with webpacker instead. I will write about that shortly!

Comment: @S.Goswami so how did you fix this problemo?

Comment: I think I have used yarn (webpacker) to install bootstrap, jquery and popper.js: https://qr.ae/pNsjrn

Gem bootstrap doesn't work as intended for Rails 6+